# cannot change layout with animation in android

Tags: android, layout, slide

I want to change layouts using `TranslateAnimation`.

**My XML is like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonsld"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textsld"
    android:text="slideup" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutsld2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsld2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsld"
    android:background="@drawable/iz"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutsld3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsld2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsld"
    android:background="@drawable/fon"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonsld2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="slidedown" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code is like

```
 private int x= 0;

buttonslideup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (x == 0) {
                    lin_lay2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lin_lay3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0);
                     slide.setDuration(1000);
                     slide.setFillAfter(true);

                     lin_lay3.startAnimation(slide);
                    x = 1;
                } else {
                    lin_lay3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    lin_lay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                     100, 0);

                     slide.setDuration(1000);
                     slide.setFillAfter(true);
                     lin_lay2.startAnimation(slide);
                    x = 0;
                }

            }
        });
```

but when I use this, at first, the `lin_lay3` slides and comes to screen and there is no problem, but when I click to button again, `lin_lay2` slides, but it is behind `lin_lay3` and I cannot see `lin_lay2`.

What I want is to change these `layouts` with the click of the `button`.

Comment: hide the linearlayout3 .. if you dont want ..

Comment: you can see in the code there is setvisibility(View.GONE) , it does not work

Comment: do like this . first check the linearlayout3 is visible or not ... according to that change the code .. and proceed

Answer (score 0):

You start another activity on button click & see the animation of your activity layout.
Just put this code after starActivity(intent).

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
```

slide_in_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/slideanim"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

slide_out_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/slideanim"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

In value folder, create integer.xml and put

```
<item name="slideanim" format="integer" type="integer">1000</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the on create, we need to type:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```