# How to implement slide animations (to left and right) with in an Activity in android 4.2?

Tags: android, slide

I am trying to implement slide animation to left and right which I was unable to complete. I have some sample code like follows,

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

When I try this in 4.2 it is showing an error like and suggesting me to "Create a field 'anim' in type 'R'" or "Create constant 'anim' in type 'R'" . Can anyone suggest me how can I overcome this problem? if any code is there to implement that will be really great.

Thanks,
Chandra.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to animate?

Comment: @g00dy, Only thing I need to do is I need to do some animation to left (when user swipes to left) or right and load next item(refresh the activity). I don't want do load another activity.

Comment: Take a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211768/cannot-change-layout-with-animation-in-android

Comment: I used it to animate a whole layout and it worked great for me. You just need to figure aut the coordinates (from start to finish).

Answer (score 1):

anim is animation folder in res dir.
slide_in_right is the xml file which needs to be created and animation information provided there.

so you need to provide both animation information in slide_in_right.xml and slide_out_left.xml files in anim folder in res dir.

Code in slide_out_left.xml can be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" android:duration="300" /> 
</set>
```

and for slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="300" /> 
  </set>
```

put these file in anim folder in res dir and it should work.

Comment: When u start the next activity using intent just before that you need to put overridePendingTransition call. overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right); Its working fine with me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually what I need is, I have main activity with in that, whenever user swipes I need to animate the view and need to load another view. For example, I would like to display "1" in the begining at the first load and when user swipe to next it the "1" view should animate to right and load the next view with the value "2" this is the flow I need. I am not sure, how many number of views and the values I need to display, that is based on the vector size.